# puppet and puppetdb debugging @@file - puppetmaster not pushing config

Tags: puppet

I am using the backuppc module that has the following code for the client:

```
@@file { "${backuppc::params::config_directory}/pc/${::fqdn}.pl":
    ensure  => $ensure,
    content => template("${module_name}/host.pl.erb"),
    owner   => 'backuppc',
    group   => $backuppc::params::group_apache,
    mode    => '0640',
    tag     => "backuppc_config_${backuppc_hostname}"
  }
```

While the backuppc server uses this code to create the files:

```
File <<| tag == "backuppc_config_${::fqdn}" |>> {
    group   => $backuppc::params::group_apache,
    notify  => Service[$backuppc::params::service],
    require => File["${backuppc::params::config_directory}/pc"],
  }
```

Twenty seven other hosts have their files written out,for some darn reason the puppet master is not pushing the config. The class on the client, puppetmaster, ran because the other components worked. I can see the class running with a do a `puppet agent --debug --test`, but I am looking for recommendations on how to debug this further. Other servers are running fine. It is the puppet master that is not pushing the config to backuppc_config tag.

There are two things that are missing:
1. a config file that is created
2. an entry in a host file for backuppc

As I mentioned multiple other servers are working, but not the darn puppetmaster, which is just kinda important to backup.

Adding notify debugging is showing that the command is running, but when I poll the /v3/resources url, the resource is not showing up.  The other resources that are not exported are showing up, but for some reason the puppet on the puppet master is not exporting that resource.

To add more fun to this I am seeing puppetdb insert the resource into the database.

```
2014-05-16 17:31:53,688 DEBUG [command-proc-69] [bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle] INSERT INTO catalog_resources (catalog_id,resource,type,title,tags,exported,file,line) VALUES (6,'14be980772ccedd05d2c7e8d31563f20159b71a1','File','/etc/backuppc/pc/myserver_redacted.com.pl',(array of type7),true,'/etc/puppet/modules/backuppc/manifests/client.pp',418)
2014-05-16 17:31:53,689 DEBUG [command-proc-69] [bonecp.PreparedStatementHandle] INSERT INTO catalog_resources (catalog_id,resource,type,title,tags,exported,file,line) VALUES (6,'65c88548872aba1ae75da554e75192279da41e8a','File_line','backuppc_host_/myserver_redacted.igivefirst.com',(array of type7),true,'/etc/puppet/modules/backuppc/manifests/client.pp',407)
```

I actually filed a bug on puppetdb on this item: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PDB-672

Comment: That is, there is another agent that imports using `File<<| tag == "backuppc_config_${backuppc_hostname}" |>>` and that doesn't happen?

Comment: See new edit - yes and I added more data

Comment: First debugging step: Copy the whole `@@file { ... }` block, enclose it in double quotes (escape or replace the double quotes that are part of the block) and assign this string to a variable, say `$export`. Then add a `notify { "debug": message => $export }` next to the actual `@@` export to see exactly what is being exported.